# Install Arch(Bang) - Create Usb - Uefi

Tags: arch-linux, usb, uefi, archbang

I am pretty new to Linux and want to install ArchBang-Linux, but I fail at creating a bootable USB-Stick.

Can someone explain this procedure to me in a little more detail?

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/UEFI#Create_UEFI_bootable_USB_from_ISO

Especially:

- First create a MBR partition table in the USB using fdisk. Mount the USB partition and create a FAT32 filesystem with LABEL as used in the Archiso configuration.
- How do I create a MBR partition table?
- How to mount?
- with LABEL? what label? as used in the Archiso config?

or do I just have to execute the shown commands? Somehow I couldn't manage to do this....

Would really appreciate any help - especially a step by step guide would be nice. I just don't know how to do this :(

Comment: The page you link to on the Arch Wiki *is* a step-by-step guide; you just have to literally paste the commands into your terminal... Of course, that is not a recommendation to do that.

Comment: # mkdir -p /mnt/{usb,iso}

this command creates an MBR File-system?!

Comment: No: `mkdir` (a contraction of 'make directory') creates the directories that you will then mount the .iso image and the USB drive to. Read through the instructions slowly; each command(s) is prefaced by a description of what is happening.

Comment: First create a MBR partition table in the USB using fdisk

This is where i have a problem.

How exactly do i do this?

Comment: `fdisk` and `gdisk` both have `man` pages: it is not difficult. Having said that, I created a UEFI bootable USB using those instructions and just skipped that step; it worked fine. Given your difficulties getting started, you might want to look at a distro that has a UEFI installer, like Fedora.